# How to run a python script which is on the host machine using docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a python script in my local machine.The file is not in the docker file directory.Is it possible to reference the path of python script inside the docker file and we able to run the script while creating container

Comment: You should just be able to run the script, `./script.py` or `python3 ./script.py`, without involving Docker.  Do you have a more specific setup that needs Docker?

Answer (score 1):

See `docker build --help`:

> ```
> Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -\
> Options:
>   -f, --file string             Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')
> ```

- The `PATH` here is `build context` which usually you will specify as `.`, means current dictory.
- Usually you won't specify `-f`, means it will use `Dockerfile` in $PATH(Usually . as current folder)

When `docker build`, docker will compress all items in `build context`, then pass it to build daemon, all files outside of `build context` can't be accessed by `Dockerfile`.

So, for your scenario, you have to change `build context` to the folder which has `py script` in it, or the parent folder. Then, specify `Dockerfile` explicitly.

A minimal example as next for your reference.

**Folder structure:**

```
cake@cake:~/20210904$ tree
.
├── docker
│   └── Dockerfile
└── run.py

1 directory, 2 files
```

**run.py:**

```
print("hello")
```

**docker/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
COPY run.py /
RUN python run.py
```

**Execution:**

```
cake@cake:~/20210904/docker$ docker build -t abc:1 -f Dockerfile ..
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/3 : FROM python:3
 ---> da24d18bf4bf
Step 2/3 : COPY run.py /
 ---> 6a4c4a76a7fb
Step 3/3 : RUN python run.py
 ---> Running in 4b736175e410
hello
Removing intermediate container 4b736175e410
 ---> 951dd3de7299
Successfully built 951dd3de7299
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

**Expalination:**

- Above change build context `PATH` to `..` to have ability to access `run.py`
- Now, the `Dockerfile` no longer the default `PATH/Dockerfile`, so we should change it to `Dockerfile` which means it in current folder.
- `COPY run.py /` implict means copy the file from `PATH/run.py`.